# How to add 1 hour to a queried time from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner for php and developing this web application, which users who registered on this site, can be claimed some scores in every one hour. When a user claims at some time, database stores that time as `time` data type in to `user_claim_time` column. When that same user tries for his next claim, this php script be able to get his last claim time and add one hour to check if the user really claims in an one hour.

So, my question is how can we add one hour to queried time. I'm using php `time(h:i:s)` function to store server's current time into the database.

Comment: Get the old time from the database and subtract it from the new time

Comment: @JosanIracheta How can we perform mathematical operations on times?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
 WHERE user_claim_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

However i recommend you to use `user_claim_time` column in `datetime` format.

Because time like this `'00:00:00'` will produce negative output as one hour subtraction can change the date or month as well. For example date like this `'2017-08-01 00:00:00'`.

So using `datetime` is the right way i think to properly compare time difference.